# What is the best place for JavaDoc files in a Maven project using Tomcat?

Tags: maven, tomcat, pom.xml, javadoc

I am regularly deploying a Maven project to a Tomcat server, using Travis CI. My project is a web app, so I have configured my `pom.xml` for building a WAR file, instead of a JAR:

```
...
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
```

With Maven, I can generate a directory containing all the JavaDoc files for my project; Maven puts them in the `target/site/apidocs` directory. But then, when I deploy my project, Travis doesn't perform any `mvn site` phase so I don't have my JavaDocs on the server.

Should I edit my `pom.xml` so that Maven puts the JavaDoc files somewhere in the `src` directory (instead of `target`) or is there a way to package the JavaDoc files together with the WAR file? I thought that I could create a `docs/` directory inside `src/main/webapp/`. Specifically: is it "good practice" to generate my JavaDoc in `src` instead of `target`? if not, how can I have a WAR file containing my JavaDoc?

What would you suggest is the best thing to do?

I already know how to generate a standalone JAR containing my JavaDoc files (see [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html)), but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why would you like to package the javadocs into the war file? They do not belong there...furthermore a JAR file should not contain javadocs as well...are you deploying internal in a company?

Comment: @khmarbaise my project is a web app, so I thought it would be nice to have a "go to the documentation" link pointing to the JavaDoc site. I am deploying to a remote AWS Tomcat server.

Comment: The web application itself should not have such possibility. Only on the development you should have such things which means deploy the appropriate `-javadoc.jar` package but not as part of the application...and it does not matter if AWS / Cloud or whatever...

Comment: I understand that the JavaDocs are not meant for production but only for development. But, if my project is open-source (on GitHub, for example), would't it be nice to have a `docs` directory in the root of my project (say, sibling to `src`) from where to build a GitHub-pages, for example?

Comment: For an open source project this is the same...deploy the artifacts to maven central where you put also the javadoc files as well...which is perfectly supprted by IDE's like Eclipse to download the appropriate javadoc as needed...never add them to resulting jar files..bloat them up...which is not needed nor a good idea... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the site plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/ and the javdoc plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html.

Add the following to your pom.xml

```
   <reporting>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                                <configuration>
                                        <links>
                                                <link>http://commons.apache.org/lang/api</link>
                                                <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api</link>
                                                <link>http://this-one-will-not-work</link>
                                        </links>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

then mvn site:site your documentation will be in target/site you can also deploy it.

Comment: Ok, so this would generate a site in `target/site/` and then I could use the Maven site plug-in for deploying it to my remote server, adding a `distributionManagement` tag to my `pom.xml`. Am I correct?

Comment: @George spot on :)  Or if you use Jenkins it will be attached to the Jenkins build so you can just share that URL.